# A question about interpreting a supply's spec

Tags: power-supply

How can I interpret this plot for [this][1] supply:

--to be edited--

Does it mean the max output current will decrease linearly with temperature but the voltage will remain the same ? What is meant by Load(%) here?

Answer (score 1):

> *Does it mean the max output current will decrease linearly with
> temperature but the voltage will remain the same between 50 and 70
> degrees?*

Yes, the voltage will remain constant up to 70°C but the availability of current to the load will linearly reduce between 50°C and 70°C for units producing higher than a 5 volt or 12 volt output.

> *What is meant by Load(%) here?*

It is a way of indicating the proportion of full load current without talking about amps. It doesn't mention amps because each power supply will have a different nominal full load current and showing all three power supply types on the same graph would appear confusing.

> *Does it mean if the nominal current is given as 10A for a model. It
> will be like 5A at 60C?*

See the graph and redlines below: -

[image]

A 15 volt power supply will be capable of supplying about 76% full load current at 60°C whereas a 5 volt output device is only capable of supplying 66% full load current at 60°C.

Comment: Does it mean if the nominal current is given as 10A for a model. It will be like 5A at 60C?

Comment: @user1245 all models will be at 50% full load current at 70 degC. At 60 degC, it depends on the model but, the 5 volt unit will be capable of supplying just over 60% full load current.

Comment: That's a different supply to the one originally linked. If that is all it tells you about derating then it's not really enough information to make any conclusive judgement @user1245 - if pushed, it seems to imply that all devices will produce 70% full load current at 70 degC. But the words "up to 70%" can mean some can reach 70% but others may be worse than 70%. Not a good spec in that respect. OK, the notes at the bottom of page 2 make it clearer. Please don't introduce a further power supply into this question. Nobody likes an evolving question.

Comment: Okay Im just on my way on the road, I will not add another just improve thanks